# specifying platform (iPad,iPhone,universal)

Tags: iphone

I am submitting my application which is iPad-specific and non-compatible for iPhone.
I made an app ID but it didn't ask me the specific platform...
so the only thing that can tell the platform of the application is the xcode setting..
Is this okay?

I hope it's not gonna be available on iPhone app store as well, as I'm making a separate one for iPhone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the Xcode setting is read by iTunes Connect when you submit. You don't need to set it anywhere else. Just make sure that **Targeted Device Family** is set to **iPad**.